# how can I perform cv2.imcode() faster?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv

Is there a way to perform the bellow line of code in a faster way?

```
arr = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(tar.extractfile(img).read(), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much faster:

```
from PIL import Image
import io
import numpy as np
import tarfile

f = io.BytesIO()
f.write(tar.extractfile(tiff).read())
f.seek(0)
arr = np.array(Image.open(f))
```

Comment: Can you prove it's "much" faster? (e.g. with a benchmark)